# Unable to track location (TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE) with Google Fit for Android

Tags: android, geolocation, google-fit

I'm trying to track location using the recording client for Google Fit on Android, but I'm unsure if it's even possible using TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE. Recording steps (TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA) and activity segments (TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT) works fine, but subscribing to TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE doesn't seem to do anything.

I can successfully subscribe to the data type TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE and I have a data source, but if I query the history client for data, there is nothing there. Again, this works for steps and activities - just not for location.

I've made sure the location permission is granted. I've moved around to change location. I've tried with `GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension` as well, still nothing. Is it not possible to record location like this, or am I just going about it the wrong way?

I'm subscribing to location data like this:

```
Fitness
    .getRecordingClient(activity, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity.applicationContext)!!)
    .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
```

I'm requesting the history data like this:

```
val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
    .read(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
    .setTimeRange(from.timeInMillis, to.timeInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build()

Fitness
    .getHistoryClient(activity, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity.applicationContext)!!)
    .readData(readRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener { dataReadResponse ->
         //returns 1 empty dataset
    }
```

Update: I've tried inserting locations manually with `HistoryClient.insertData` just to see if I could get something to work that way. I still can't get any data when querying the history, but the distance delta has changed based on the locations I've added, so something is happening. But I still can't get the actual *locations* from history.

Answer (score 0):

You can only read location data that your app wrote.

This is described in the [Exceptions](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/public#exceptions) section in the Public Data Types documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm subscribing to TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE in the same app that I'm querying the history though - so shouldn't it be ok?